# Faster R-CNN ResNet101 V1 800x1333 Ignore pre-trained weight

Tags: model, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, weighted

if I need to train my model according to my domain and ignore the pre-trained weights and build my model with same Faster R-CNN ResNet101 V1 800x1333 architecture  from scratch what should I do

using Tensorflow2

I would like to use  this Model in another domain not Cats , dogs , ... , I can run and configure it with my domain changing classes and added my own data but my question it pretrained weights still used on my own data – weights that result from Dogs , cats , … or it will initializing

Comment: What did you already try to do ? See [ask]

Comment: try this Model in another domain not Cats , dogs , ... , i can run and configure it with my domain change classes and added my own data but my question it pretrained weights still initiated on my own data